# MySQL2 Gem is failing following a MacBooKpro OS upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

```
OS: MacOS Monterey-version 12.3
Rails 7.0.2
Ruby 3.1.0
MySQL gem: mysql2 (0.5.3) (from Gemfile.lock)
```

My app Rails development server was running great, until Apple said I should update to Monterey version 12.3, which included an xcode update.

I next tried to run the db migrate:

```
rake db:migrate
```

To which I received the following message:

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/joseph-mac/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 0x0009): Library not loaded: libssl.1.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/joseph-mac/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: tried: 'libssl.1.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/joseph-mac/ProxLearn/Development/PLIConnectV2/repositories/pli2_tw/libssl.1.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib' (no such file) - /Users/joseph-mac/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

My original MySQL2 gem was built as follows:

```
gem install mysql2 -- --with-opt-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1 –with-mysql-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql
```

And as far as I remember, this is where homebrew was. I tried looking for the files:

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1
```

And the response was:

```
no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1
```

The following:

```
ls -l /opt/homebrew
```

Produces:

```
ls: /opt/homebrew: No such file or directory
```

Which means that the OS upgrade eradicated the /opt/homebrew, or at least eradicated the Symlinks to it.

However, doing:

```
brew list
```

Produces:

```
==> Formulae
...  openssl@1.1
...  openssl@3
```

Digging further into it, it looks like the homebrew real folder, is at:

```
/usr/local/Cellar
```

And I found the following folders:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1m/include
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1m/lib
```

Great, so off to build the MySQL2 gem again:

```
gem install mysql2 -- --with-opt-dir=ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1m/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1m/include
```

And the response is:

```
Building native extensions with: '--with-opt-dir=ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1m/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1m/include'
This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.5.3
1 gem installed
```

But, when I run:

```
rake db:migrate
```

I get the exact same error I started with.

When I do:

```
which openssl
```

The response is:

```
/usr/bin/openssl
```

Which is an executable, not a folder.

I tried uninstalling the MySQL2 gem before every step, and then re-installing, and then re-bundling. Same error.

Any ideas?

## Fix:

The fix that worked for me (essentially allowing homebrew to fix all the links that the Monterey update broke):

```
brew update --preinstall
brew install openssl@1.1
```

Then when this is done, add the following to ~/.zshrc:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
```

And adding the following line, as the last statement in ~/.zshrc:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
```

To make sure the homebrew installed openssl@1.1 is the one to go, instead of the one installed in /usr/local/bin

Then restart your terminal, and do the following:

```
gem install mysql2 -- --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1 –with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/opt/mysql
```

This should fix the problem.

Comment: Please add answers as answers rather than as part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.
I could solve it with the following.

```
% sudo gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.3' -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql
```